# Finding all the analytic functions $f: \Bbb D \to \Bbb C$ such that:

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)^2+2zf(z)+1=0$. $\,$ $\forall z\in\Bbb C \,where \,\Bbb D=\{x\in \Bbb C; |x|\lt 1\}$ is the unit circle.

Solving this quadratic equation I have that $f(z)= -z\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}$.

That can be written in this form: $f(z) = z\pm e^{\frac{log(z^2-1)}{2}}$. Supose we take the principal branch of the argument. Thus the logarithm is analytic in $\Bbb C\setminus(\infty,0].$

How should I continue?

Comment: You should use that branch of the square root that is holomorphic on $\mathbb C\setminus [0,\infty)$. Then $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb D$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Any branch of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb D$. Not that there are that many...

Comment: I should have written "could" instead of "should"... Denoting the branches of the square root by $\sqrt[-]{}$ and $\sqrt[+]{}$ (cut at $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$, resp.), there is also the solution $\sqrt[+]{z-1}\sqrt[-]{z+1}$. The question is whether this solution eventually coincides with $\sqrt[+]{z^2-1}$.

Comment: There are exactly two $f\in H(\Bbb D)$ with $f^2=z^2-1$. Your function is one or the other.